# Why is a contact form getting spammed even after adding captcha?

Tags: web-hosting, spam, spam-prevention

A client was getting a lot of spam from a form on their site. I added Captcha and changed the form fields and form recipient email address, but the client is still receiving spam from the server, with the original form fields to the original email address.

Does anyone know what this is and how I can stop it?

Comment: Have you tried submitting a form via curl to see what happens?

Comment: Im not sure how curl works, sorry

Comment: Try making your own form on a separate website and submit it to their form and see what happens

Comment: Does the email that the person is receiving have a physical mailbox.  If so, disable the mailbox.  See [also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319942/preventing-bot-form-submission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. Your attempt at adding captcha can be bypassed.
2. The email address is known and the spam is not coming through the contact form.

Its very hard to tell exactly what is wrong without a link to the site to investigate.

I am the author of [free open source contact form software](http://ostermiller.org/contactform/) that is designed to solve this very problem.   My contact form:

- Never reveals email addresses through the web interface
- Has spam prevention features that can be enabled such as

  - bot traps
  - required preview
  - captcha
  - HTML not allowed in messages

I would suggest that you change the email address and install my contact form software.